# Symmetric difference and convergence of sequence of sets

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

I have two question regards to symmetric different and a convergent sequence of a set:-

if we have a sequence of sets $\{X_i\}$.then how to show that:-

- $\{X_i\}$ is convergent if and only if if for any two sequences of natural numbers $\{m_k\},\{n_k\}$ with limit infinity, we have $\cap_k (X_{m_{k}}\Delta X_{n_{k}})=\emptyset$.
- $\{X_i\}$ is convergent if and only if if for any two sequences of natural numbers 
  $\{m_k\},\{n_k\}$ with limit infinity, we have $ lim_{k\rightarrow} \infty(X_{m_{k}}\Delta X_{n_{k}})=\emptyset$.

I know $\{X_n\}$ is convergent if $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}sup\ X_n=lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}inf X_n\, $.

Comment: How are the $X_i$ and $A_n$ related?

Comment: @copper.hat sorry for the error,they are same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Recall that

$$\limsup_nX_n=\bigcap_{n\ge 0}\bigcup_{m\ge n}X_m=\{x:x\in X_n\text{ for infinitely many }n\in\Bbb N\}$$

and

$$\liminf_nX_n=\bigcup_{n\ge 0}\bigcap_{m\ge n}X_m=\{x:x\in X_n\text{ for all but finitely many }n\in\Bbb N\}\;.$$

These are equal if and only if every $x$ that’s in infinitely many of the sets $X_n$ is in all of them from some point on. To put it a little differently, for each $x$ there is an $n_x\in\Bbb N$ such that either $x\in X_n$ for all $n\ge n_x$, or $x\notin X_n$ for all $n\ge n_x$.

Suppose that $\limsup_nX_n=\liminf_nX_n$, and let $\langle m_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ and $\langle n_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be sequences in $\Bbb N$ such that $\lim_km_k=\lim_kn_k=\infty$. If $x\in\bigcap_{k\in\Bbb N}(X_{m_k}\mathrel{\triangle}X_{n_k})$, then for each $k\in\Bbb N$ either $x\in X_{m_k}\setminus X_{n_k}$, or $x\in X_{n_k}\setminus X_{m_k}$. Clearly at least one of these alternatives must occur infinitely often; without loss of generality suppose that $M=\{k\in\Bbb N:x\in X_{m_k}\setminus X_{n_k}\}$ is infinite.

- Explain why this implies that $\{n\in\Bbb N:x\in X_n\}$ is infinite.
- Conclude that there is an $n_x\in\Bbb N$ such that $x\in X_n$ for all $n\ge n_x$.
- Use the fact that $M$ is infinite to derive a contradiction, and conclude that $\bigcap_{k\in\Bbb N}(X_{m_k}\mathrel{\triangle}X_{n_k})$ must be empty.

Conversely, suppose that $\limsup_nX_n\ne\liminf_nX_n$.

- Show that there is an $x$ such that $\{n\in\Bbb N:x\in X_n\}$ and $\{n\in\Bbb N:x\notin X_n\}$ are both infinite.
- Use this fact to construct sequences $\langle m_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ and $\langle n_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ in $\Bbb N$ such that $x\in X_{m_k}\setminus X_{n_k}$ for every $k\in\Bbb N$, and hence $x\in\bigcap_{k\in\Bbb N}(X_{m_k}\mathrel{\triangle}X_{n_k})$.

For the second question show that $\lim_k(X_{m_k}\mathrel{\triangle}X_{n_k})=\varnothing$ iff $\limsup_k(X_{m_k}\mathrel{\triangle}X_{n_k})=\varnothing$. Then make appropriate modifications to the two arguments sketched above.

Comment: Hi Brian. I'm trying to solve a similar question to this, but I can't figure it out even re-arranging what you did. Can you give me any help? If yes, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4629111/1098713! Thank you!